# Can we find a unitary matrix to remove entries?

Tags: matrices, unitary-matrices

Does there exists a $3\times 3$ unitary matrix $U$ such
$$
U\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a\\
0 & 1 & b\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is either $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & x\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & y\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ where $x\neq b$ and $y\neq a$ are complex numbers.(Before this question was edited, the condition was that $x=b$ and $y=a$.)

Answer (score 5):

Multiplication by a unitary matrix preserves the norm of a vector.  The last column of $UB$ is $U$ times the last column of $B$, and for a unitary matrix you can't have $U \pmatrix{a\cr b \cr 1} = \pmatrix{0 \cr b \cr 1}$ unless $a=0$, or $\pmatrix{a \cr 0 \cr 1}$ unless $b = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If we change the condition in this way that the last column is not necessarily $(0,b,1)^T$, i.e, $(0,x,1)^T$ where $x\neq b$, then can we say there exists a unitary matrix $U$ satisfying the condition above?

Comment: If $U B = C$ and $B$ is invertible (which it is here), then $U = C B^{-1}$.  That may or may not be unitary...

Comment: But note that an upper triangular matrix is unitary if and only if it is diagonal with diagonal entries of absolute value $1$.